# O que significa "desembaraço imediato" aqui?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

O que significa conferir *"desembaraço imediato"* no contexto seguinte? Que o produto faz com que o cabelo fique macio imediatamente ou o que?

> XY CREAM – Linha XY Style Professional. Creme de uso diário de hidratação e finalização dos fios, com multi benefícios, que é utilizado antes ou depois dos serviços térmicos. Confere reparação, hidratação, fortalecimento, disciplina, controle do volume, proteção térmica, **desembaraço imediato**, proteção UV, brilho e intensa maciez para todos os tipos de cabelos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta é a definição da palavra embaraço segundo o Google, onde diz que *qualquer fato ou coisa que dificulta ou impede; dificuldade, complicação, atrapalhação*.

[image: definição de embaraço]

A palavra desembaraço refere-se ao antônimo de *embaraço*, portanto, é possível definir desembaraço como, *qualquer fato ou coisa que desimpede*.

Neste contexto que você apresentou, como se está falando de produtos de beleza (espeficamente produtos para o cabelo), a palavra *desembaraço* refere-se a aos fios de cabelo deixando-o mais bonito e consequentemente mais mácio.

Segue duas fotos abaixo, sendo a primeira foto um cabelo **embaraçado** e a segunda um cabelo **desembaraçado**.

[image: tipos de cabelo]

E a palavra imediato, é um adjetivo que descreve o *desembaraço* como precedente ou subsequente a uma ação. Neste contexto, logo após o uso do creme para o cabelo, acontecerá o desembaraço, portanto, **desembaraço imediato**.

A palavra imediato muitas vezes traz consigo uma conotação de *eficiência*, onde os resultados de um certo produto são eminentes, subentende-se com isso, que esse produto é de qualidade.

Comment: Agradeço muito sua resposta, sua explicação e seu tempo, João. Então, desembaraço aqui significa fazer com que os fios não fiquem "tangled" como nesta foto. https://www.google.com.eg/search?safe=strict&biw=1536&bih=735&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=fios+emaranhados&oq=fios+emaranhados&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.4746.8792.0.9207.8.8.0.0.0.0.164.981.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.405...0i8i30k1.sqP5yGcCjBw#imgrc=bUwIMKpDxNwK4M:

Obrigada!!!